# Why isn't favicon working?

Tags: html, web, icons, favicon, bluehost

I've been banging my head against the wall for hours now trying to get this favicon to work.  My site is hosted on Bluehost and I uploaded a favicon.ico file to the public_html folder. It always just shows the default Bluehost logo in both Safari and Chrome. I included the following in the header after all the meta tags:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Have tried icon sizes 16x16 and 32x32, always named favicon.ico, and also tried putting href="http://www.mydomainname.com/favicon.ico" in the tag. I am always clearing the cache before trying to load the site.

If I inspect the page source in Chrome, I see the link for the favicon, and the page source page in Chrome shows the favicon correctly. When I click on the favicon link then try to load the site, the favicon I want flashes briefly before going back to the default Bluehost one.

In case it matters, I just migrated the site from Wordpress and deleted all the "wp" files, but maybe something is left that's screwing it up. Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Did it work before the migration?

Comment: Yes, it did. Uploaded it to Wordpress that time.

Comment: I'm not sure if that gets cleared from the cache when you clear the browser cache but what you can try is adding a cache-buster to the path. ex: favicon.ico?ver=20130212

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if that gets cleared from the cache when you clear the browser cache but what you can try is adding a cache-buster to the path. ex: `favicon.ico?ver=20130212`